# Create shake animation for UIImageView that is possible to start and stop

Tags: objective-c

I need to shake an UIImageView when an event occurs, I use the following code for the shake animation:

```
CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [shake setDuration:0.1];
    [shake setRepeatCount:INFINITY];
    [shake setAutoreverses:YES];
    [shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                         CGPointMake(_clockImg.center.x - 5,_clockImg.center.y)]];
    [shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                       CGPointMake(_clockImg.center.x + 5, _clockImg.center.y)]];
    [_clockImg.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];
```

The problem is that I can't stop the animation when I want to, I tried with `[_clockImg stopAnimating];` and changing the `[shake setRepeatCount:0];` but the animation keeps going. Is there a way to stop a CABasicAnimation like I want to?

Comment: UIImage can't be animated, It would be UIImageView ;)

Comment: If you want it to repeat for any Specified times then just set it's Repeatcount, not INFINITY/0.

Comment: @Mrug yeah sorry I've edited my question, btw Danny's solution worked

Comment: That's fine, I have provided another way to remove specific Animation from multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
[image.layer removeAllAnimations]
```

Comment: Correct one !! If want to remove all animations from a Layer.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have multiple Animations on particular Layer and want to remove only specific one,i.e. in your case its "position" (`[_clockImg.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"]`)

```
[_clockImg.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"position"];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's should help you

pause animation:

```
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
layer.speed = 0.0;
layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
```

resume animation:

```
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
layer.speed = 1.0;
layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
```

stop all animations:

```
[layer removeAllAnimations];
```

stop animation with key = @"animationKey":

```
[layer removeAnimationForKey:@"animationKey"];
```